# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript - Jest, Nodejs, Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I'm getting an error when i run the yarn test. Apparently the error is in the jest.cofig.ts in the object "moduleNameMapper".

I think it's in that file because if I remove the line the tests "work" (it doesn't actually test anything, but it doesn't give the error either.)

jest.config.ts

```
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property and type check, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
 */
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest/utils';

import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json';

export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    verbose: true,
    clearMocks: true,
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/index.ts'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/setup.ts'],
    testEnvironment: 'node',

    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>' }),
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/@types"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@infrastructure/*": ["./src/infrastructure/*"],
      "@useCases/*": ["./src/use-cases/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["./src/tests/*"],
      "@domain/*": ["./src/domain/*"],
      "@messagesConsumers/*": ["./src/messages-consumers/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

package.json -> scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test tsnd -r tsconfig-paths/register --transpile-only src/tests/init.ts",
    "test2": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "prepare": "husky install && yarn husky set .husky/pre-commit 'yarn lint-staged'",
    "setup:dev": "NODE_ENV=development tsnd -r tsconfig-paths/register --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules --no-notify src/setup/setup.ts",
    "setup:production": "NODE_ENV=production tsnd -r tsconfig-paths/register --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules --no-notify src/setup/setup.ts"
  },
```

yarn test error message:

```
Failed to parse the TypeScript config file /var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/jest.config.ts
  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
jest.config.ts:16:24 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

16     moduleNameMapper: (0, utils_1.pathsToModuleNameMapper)(tsconfig_json_1.compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>' }),
                          ~

    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:136:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at readConfig (/var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:225:18)
    at readConfigs (/var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:420:26)
    at runCLI (/var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:132:59)
    at initialize (/var/www/nodejs/necata-gateway/src/tests/init.ts:29:23)
```

Answer (score 1):

I still dont understand why this error.... But i changed the object "moduleNameMapper" by removing the function and adding an array with my folder paths.

```
export default {
preset: 'ts-jest',
transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',
},
verbose: true,
clearMocks: true,
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/index.ts'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/setup.ts'],
testEnvironment: 'node',

// moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>' }),
moduleNameMapper: {
    // '^@App/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    // '^lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/common/$1',

    '^@useCases/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/use-cases/$1',
    '^@tests/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/$1',
    '^@domain/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/domain/$1',
    '^@messagesConsumers/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/messages-consumers/$1',
    '^@infrastructure/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/infrastructure/$1',
},
};
```

And now my tests run...